# What are workarounds for multiple line HTML option tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to do the following as shown in the [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ClzI.png). The basic idea is the user can select one (or multiple) item(s) and click the arrow to move the items from one box to another. The key feature is each option must be multiple lines.

The way I am currently doing this is by using two HTML select boxes, and two buttons. Each item is an option. However, because options cannot contain multiple lines or tags, I only have the name of the item, and not the price or description.

For this reason, I am looking for a solution that is not necessarily an HTML option tag. A workaround I have been reading about is using the `<title>` tag, but that is not a solution I want to use.

I was planning on using HTML tables with jQuery to detect clicks, and change attributes of each individual row in CSS to give the illusion it is selected, etc, but before I build this I would like some other ideas, as there must be some other solution out there that is more mature.

Please note data needs to be brought in from an external SQL database. Currently I use an .ashx handler to generate the front end code from the backend. IE `<option value={0}>{0}</option>` is returned to the front end between the select tags via an AJAX call.

Please share your thoughts on what might do this best.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or invites discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

> I was planning on using HTML tables

It looks like tabular data (product name, price) so tables are fine.

> with jQuery to detect clicks, and change attributes of each individual row in CSS to give the illusion it is selected, etc,

Be [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), use checkboxes. You can detect clicks on the row and toggle the checkbox to expand the click area.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about setting the options with a `value` as their reference in a table on your db?
for example, a db could store the following:

```
ID   = 1
Name = Orange
Type = Valencia
Price= $2.50
```

Then, your options could look like this:

```
<select name='fruit'> 
  <option value='1'> Orange </option> 
  <option value='2'> Banana </option> 
  <option value='3'> Apple </option> 
</select>
```

When the user submits the form data, you could take `$_POST['name']` and use it as criteria to search your database to find gather all the data on the items they selected.